# Using ZFS with little RAM?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, zfs

I have an Acer EasyStore with a RAID5 mdraid array I use for storing my home files (photos, movies, etc), and I want to migrate it to ZFS with Ubuntu (the native kernel module from zfsonlinux.org).

I hear that ZFS needs a lot of RAM, but the EasyStore only has 2 GB. The RAIDZ will be three 1.5GB disks, and I'm wondering if ZFS won't work with 2 GB of RAM. What problems, if any, am I likely to see? Performance isn't a concern, as long as it can stream HD movies in real time, which is basically the use case this computer sees.

Comment: Yes, [my ZFS NAS](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/14/building-a-nas-server-2/) runs fine with just 2 GB of memory. The performance isn't stellar (which may be more to do with the network, or the CPU), but it can certainly stream HD films.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, even with a small RAM footprint. ZFS uses RAM as a caching layer and for some of the advanced features like deduplication. Don't expect any boost in performance over what you have now, though.

Comment: That's fine, I only want it for the improved RAID capabilities, checksumming and various other features. Thank you.